# C++ template instantiation with shared_ptr to const T

Tags: c++, constants, shared-ptr, implicit-conversion, template-argument-deduction

Suppose I have a class

```
template <typename T>
class A {
 public:
  template <typename V>
    void f(std::tr1::shared_ptr<const std::vector<V> > v1, 
           std::tr1::shared_ptr<const std::vector<float> > v2) {}
};
```

The following does not compile:

```
 A<string> a;
  std::tr1::shared_ptr<std::vector<float> > v1(new std::vector<float>());
  std::tr1::shared_ptr<std::vector<float> > v2(new std::vector<float>());
  a.f(v1, v2);
```

The compiler error is:

```
error: no matching function for call to 'A<std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > >::f(std::tr1::shared_ptr<std::vector<float, std::allocator<float> > >&, std::tr1::shared_ptr<std::vector<float, std::allocator<float> > >&)'
```

The compiler could not make `std::tr1::shared_ptr<std::vector<float> >`  into 
`std::tr1::shared_ptr<const std::vector<float> >` for the first argument. Yet it could for the second (non-template argument).

One solution to this is to change the call to f(), call it like this `f<float>(...)`.
Another solution is to declare v1 as shared_ptr to `const vector<float>.`

1. Why is template instantiation behaving so differently here?
2. My understanding of having a `shared_ptr<const T>` as argument to a method is that the method cannot change what the `shared_ptr` is pointing to. If we change the `shared_ptr`s to raw pointers and `v1`, `v2` as raw pointers to `vectors`, then the code will compile fine. What is it about `shared_ptr`s that breaks template deduction?

Comment: A third solution is to change `v1` to `std::tr1::shared_ptr<V>`.

Comment: But I don't want to do that, since I want to ensure that f does not change the argument in any way. All that can change is how I declare v1 and v2 in the calling code a.f(...).

Comment: I didn't expect you to like this, it's just that your enumeration of possible solutions seemed incomplete. `:)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Why is template instantiation behaving so differently here?

A `shared_ptr<T>` is implicitly convertible to a `shared_ptr<const T>` via a converting constructor.  Unfortunately, such conversions cannot be used during template argument deduction.

In order for argument deduction to succeed, the type of the argument has to match the type of the parameter exactly; most conversions, including user-defined conversions, are not used.

Only a few very basic conversions are allowed, including array-to-pointer decay and function-to-function-pointer conversion (since no function parameter can be of array type or function type, these conversions cannot lead to confusion).  In addition, top-level const- and volatile- qualifiers are wholly ignored.

Comment: "_the type of the argument has to **match the type of the parameter exactly**_" no, qualification and derived-to-base conversion can be applied. "_top-level const- and volatile- qualifiers are wholly ignored._" where?

Comment: @curiousguy:  That is incorrect. The derived-to-base conversion is not permitted during argument deduction.  The most basic example is `struct B { }; struct D { }; template <typename T> void f(T x, T y) { } int main() { f(B(), D()); }`, which fails due to ambiguity, even though a derived-to-base conversion could resolve the ambiguity, were it permitted.  "Top-level qualifiers" are those not nested in a type.  For example, the `const` in `int* const` is top-level, whereas the `const` in `int const*` is not.

Comment: "_That is incorrect._" What I wrote is perfectly correct: I wrote "can be applied" not "are applied, always". "_even though a derived-to-base conversion could resolve the ambiguity_" It isn't an ambiguity, it is a contradiction: `T` = `B` and `T` = `D`. "_"Top-level qualifiers" are those not nested in a type._" I know. Top-level qualifiers are "wholly ignored" where? when? It's somewhat more complicated than what you describe.

Comment: @curiousguy:  Would you provide an example of the derived-to-base conversion taking place during argument deduction?

Comment: Only when a parameter is a templated base class.

Comment: @curiousguy:  An example would be much appreciated.

Comment: `template <class T> int f(Base<T>); f(Der<int>());`

Comment: @curiousguy:  I see what you're getting at now.

Answer (score 4):

## Related types?

As you know, `T*` and `const T*` are related types. There is a standard conversion from the first to the second (qualification conversion).

First, you have to realise that `A<T>` and `A<const T>` are not in general related types. These type could have different size, representation, and purpose. One could be defined but not the other.

In particular, `A<const T>` is not a const qualified `A<T>`, so there is no qualification-conversion between the two, and C++ is not flexible enough to declared user-defined qualification-conversions. (A user cannot declare any **standard** conversion, only user-defined conversion - user-defined conversion are not standard conversions.)

So user-defined types are fundamentally different from fundamental types: they cannot be related the way fundamental types are.

## `shared_ptr<>`

`shared_ptr<>` is designed to form a family of compatible types: `shared_ptr<T>` is implicitly convertible to `shared_ptr<U>` iff `T*` is implicitly convertible to `U*`. In particular, `shared_ptr<T>` is implicitly convertible to `shared_ptr<const T>`. It is also implicitly convertible to `shared_ptr<void>`, so the same reason.

Because types `shared_ptr<const T>` and `shared_ptr<T>` are not related in any special way, the conversion from `shared_ptr<T>` to `shared_ptr<const T>` is not distinguished from `shared_ptr<T>` to `shared_ptr<void>`. These are just two different conversions, but neither can be considered "preferred" in any context, unlike the conversion from `T*` to `const T*` (rank = Exact match) which is preferred over conversion from `T*` to `void*` (rank = Conversion).

## Function templates

Some standard conversions are allowed on deduced templates function arguments:

- qualification conversions
- some pointer conversions: derived-to-base
- ...

But as we have seen, no such conversions exist between `shared_ptr<>` types.

This means that even if the compiler was allowed to enumerate all possible types for a template parameter to turn a function template

```
template <typename V>
void f (shared_ptr<const T> v1);
```

into an infinite set of functions prototypes:

```
for every type T,
such that shared_ptr<const T> can be instantiated:
f (shared_ptr<const T>)
```

unless you have an exact match, you would not be able to call a function: given the declarations

```
struct Base {};
struct Derived : Base {};

shared_ptr<Derived> d;
```

among the set of `f` prototypes, there is:

```
f (shared_ptr<const Base>)
f (shared_ptr<const Derived>)
```

so a call to `f (d)` would be ambiguous as both of these candidates involve different user-defined conversions.